2-Dimensional Cosmology and Power Spectrum
First, full disclosure, I am not even sure yet if this question makes sense, but I tried to derive some stuff, and would love some feedback.
First, recall that in $d=4$, we can write the de Sitter metric (that will pertain to an inflation spacetime, so we are approximately de Sitter) as
\begin{equation}
ds^2 = \frac{1}{H^2\eta^2}\left(-d\eta^2 + d\mathbf{x}^2\right)
\end{equation}
where $d\mathbf{x}^2 = \delta_{ij}dx^idx^j$. The metric is conformal so I can write $g_{\mu\nu} = a^2\eta_{\mu\nu}$ using $a = -1/H\eta$ where $H$ is the Hubble constant. We can consider a massive scalar field in this de Sitter background and solve the mode-function equation to find the mode functions of the massive scalar field that correspond to de Sitter, but (for reasons) I want to do the same procedure in $d=2$ (see the lecture notes by Baumann and Joyce here: Lectures on Cosmological Correlators).
So, I reduce to $d=2$, my metric above looks the same except $d\mathbf{x}^2\rightarrow dx^2$ with only 1-spatial direction. My action for the massive scalar field is (where $\sqrt{-g} = a^2(\eta)$, but typically in $d=4$ is the usual $\sqrt{-g} = a^4(\eta)$)
\begin{align}
S &= \int dx^2\sqrt{-g}\left(-\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu\phi\partial_\nu\phi - \frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2\right)\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\int d\eta dx\left(\dot{\phi}^2 - (\nabla\phi)^2 - a^2m^2\phi^2\right)
\end{align}
where $\dot{\phi}\equiv d\phi/d\eta$. Already, the situation is different since the kinetic term is already canonical (typically, there is a factor of $a^2$ on the kinetic term, so you substitute $u = a(\eta)\phi$ to make the kinetic term canonical). So, I can Fourier transform and then find the equations of motion which are
\begin{equation}
\ddot{\phi} + \left(k^2 + \frac{m^2}{H^2\eta^2}\right)\phi = 0.
\end{equation}
If I write $x\equiv -k\eta$ then I can put this differential equation into the form of
\begin{equation}
x^2\frac{d^2u}{dx^2} + (x^2+\nu^2)u = 0
\end{equation}
where $\nu^2\equiv m^2/H^2$. But, to relate back to the usual case for the massive scalar in $d=4$, I can go further and instead define $u(\eta)\equiv \sqrt{x}g(x)$ which gives me
\begin{equation}
x^2\frac{d^2g}{dx^2} + x\frac{dg}{dx} + (x^2 - y^2)g(x) = 0
\end{equation}
if I define $y\equiv \sqrt{\frac{1}{4} - \frac{m^2}{H^2}}$. The typical value of $y$ in $d=4$ is $\sqrt{\frac{9}{4} - \frac{m^2}{H^2}}$. I would assume then that I would get the same massive de Sitter mode as in $d=4$ but with different "weight" $\nu$ (given in E.26 of the lecture notes I referenced).
Now, here are my questions before I even proceed further. If my math above is correct, then the mode function has the same structure in $d=2$ as it does in $d=4$ for a massive scalar but a different weight $\nu$ (which I labeled as $y$ above). But, the supposed power spectrum then of this universe (a weird one at that) is then not a surface, but just a singular point correct? I would then need to instead compute
\begin{equation}
\langle 0|\hat{\phi}_k(\eta,x)\hat{\phi}(\eta,0)|0\rangle = \int \frac{dk}{2\pi}P(k)e^{ik\cdot x}\:\:\: ?
\end{equation}
I have no idea if what I am even doing is valid, but luckily there is a place like this to ask (since this is all speculative and nothing near the norm of $d=4$ cosmology). Thanks for any feedback or criticism in advance.
EDIT: I believe my derivation is correct for massive scalar as given in section 4.1 in Maldacena's paper Two dimensional Nearly de Sitter gravity, but I can't see (quickly) any reference to the power spectrum. So if someone could translate to some good-ole observational cosmology that'd be great...

I'm not really sure what you're asking, but sure, you can follow the calculation of scalar perturbations in an inflationary background in any dimension. (For tensor modes, you should end up finding that there are no tensor modes in 2 spacetime dimensions).  I doubt it has any physical significance but mathematically it's fine. Another thing that seems relevant is that your equal time correlation function is defined on a line, not a point. The analogue of a 3+1 split in 2 spacetime dimensions is a 1+1 split, so at equal times you have 1 spatial dimension, a line.
